# bind listbox to index C#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, listbox

I dont know if it  possible but what I want is something like that 
In `WinForm` `listbox1` has a list of lines(copied from file)

In another Thread and class I run on a List that contains the same lines each line I parse and `DoSomething`
once I finish with that line I want the index in the listbox to change

from my basic and limited understanding my approach was with an `Event` to fire in form and than maybe using Invoke (for not to cross thread )

Is there is a way to somehow bind to index of the `listbox` somehow with my `for/foreach` loop ?

```
class form
{
    listBoxScript.SetSelected(ScriptCounter, true);<--bind the ScriptCounter?
}
```

in another Class

```
class RunScript
{
//..

    public void RunScriptList()
    {
        ScriptCounter = 0 ;
        foreach ( var cell in ScriptList)
        {
        ScriptCounter ++;
        //DoSomething
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you meant by bind o index of the listbox somehow with my for/foreach loop? What does loops has to do with binding? Posting some code would help.

Comment: I'll Add some code to make it more clear

Comment: Also mention which technology. Winforms or WPF? I presume it is winforms

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Done == winform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `RunScript` class. Here's a complete sample:

```
class RunScript : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int scriptCounter;

    private ISynchronizeInvoke invoker;
    public RunScript(ISynchronizeInvoke invoker)
    {
        if (invoker == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("invoker");
        this.invoker = invoker;
    }

    public async void RunScriptList()
    {
        ScriptCounter = 0;
        foreach (var cell in Enumerable.Range(1, 15))
        {
            ScriptCounter++;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            //DoSomething
        }
    }

    public int ScriptCounter
    {
        get { return scriptCounter; }
        set
        {
            scriptCounter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            Action action = () => handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            invoker.Invoke(action, null);
        }
    }
}

private RunScript rs;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    rs = new RunScript(this)

    var binding = new Binding("SelectedIndex", rs, "ScriptCounter", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    listBox1.DataBindings.Add(binding);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rs.RunScriptList();
}
```

Note I have used `async/await` in `RunScriptList`, If you do it in another thread you need to fire `PropertyChanged` event in main thread to avoid cross thread exception.

Comment: Thank you very Much !
If I use Invoke to fire OnPropertyChanged in Main thread (where Form is running ) It would be fine ? or I need to do it with an Event ?

Comment: Yes, Invoke inside `OnPropertyChanged` is fine, or else you can use [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.SynchronizationContext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `Send` or `Post` method

Comment: I'm afraid I'm in too deep for 'SynchronizationContext' ,Is it will be too much to ask you to post How would you implement the Invoke ?
I'm going to mark it as an answer in a few moments

Comment: Updated my code to use `Invoke`, You need to pass `ISynchronizeInvoke` to `RunScript` class, If `ISynchronizeInvoke` is new to you, don't be afraid `Form` implements that interface. Strictly speaking you can pass any `Control`. and... You're welcome :)

Comment: sadly I get "Cannot bind to the property 'ScriptListBox' on the target control." when putting the code ...

Comment: I guess you don't have the property named `ScriptListBox` or both are of incompatible types. That's indeed another question, I suggest you to ask new question with all necessary information with relevant code if problem is not solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58351/discussion-between-lordtitikaka-and-sriram-sakthivel).