# How can I set selected in a ComboBox, based on ValueMember?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox with the following structure. Also, I am getting a **fld_id** from another source and based on that id I need to select the corresponding item in the ComboBox. How can I do that?

```
comboBoxCustomers.DataSource = customers;

comboBoxCustomers.ValueMember = "fld_id";

comboBoxCustomers.DisplayMember = "fld_name";
```

Example:

List could contain these items

```
fld_id   fld_name

65       Item1

68       Item2

69       Item3
```

I need to set Item 68 as selected.

Comment: What do you meany by *I am getting a fld_id from another source and based on that id I need to select the corresponding item in the ComboBox*? Post some more code to show how you get `fld_id`? Is that a property?

Comment: It doesn't matter where it comes from. I just need to select the item with that id as valuemember

Comment: what happens when you: `var selected = comboBoxCustomers.SelectedValue;` ?

Comment: Actually, it matters! If it is a property you can use [binding to bind it as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25030968/2530848). Though am not sure whether it will work in this scenario.

Comment: @Apostrofix NO! I need to set it as selected. There is nothing selected. I am building the ComboBox

Comment: try this : comboBoxCustomers.SelectedValue = 68;

Comment: okay, so if i understood you correctly, this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864065/c-sharp-set-combo-item-with-selectedvalue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Following:

```
comboBoxCustomers.SelectedValue = fld_id(which you are getitng from another source)
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment. This:

```
comboBoxCustomers.SelectedValue = fld_id
```

works great :) But **AFTER** showing the form, otherwise it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

if you use datasource of the combobox, you can cast the datasource back to the list, find the item and use that item to set the selected item:

```
var stores = cbxStores.DataSource as List<store>;
var store = stores.Where(w => w.store_code == _station.store_code).FirstOrDefault();
cbxStores.SelectedItem = store;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest procdure I found for myself:

You can bind it into some function with perameters while funtion is called.

Hope it is going to help you guys:

```
int Idd = Convert.ToInt32(your value for the combobox  you want to be selected);
for (int i = 0; i < myComboBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    myComboBox.SelectedIndex = i;
    if (Convert.ToInt32( myComboBox.SelectedValue ) == Idd )
        {break;}                   
}
```